# swift - Remove white spaces from var(UITextField input) doesn't work

Tags: ios, string, swift, var, unwrap

I'm new to swift, but from ObjectiveC background, I tried to get an input from textfield into a var, on a button click.

Now, when I tried to remove blank space using "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet" and so many other options, it's not working. Here is my code,

```
    var someVariable = urlInputComponent.text!
    if someVariable.containsString(" "){
        someVariable = someVariable.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        print(someVariable)

    }
```

I also tried by assigning the result to a new var,

```
        let trimmed: String = someVariable.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        print(trimmed)
```

but still couldn't remove the whitespace. My guess is I'm confusing with the "Unwrapped value" concept, it'll be really helpful if someone could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the docs, `someVariable.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet ` returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the String characters contained in a given character set, so it's working as intended - see @Anbu's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the alternate way

```
 urlInputComponent.text! = urlInputComponent.text!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

or else try this

```
let trimmed = "".join(urlInputComponent.text!.characters.map({ $0 == " " ? "" : String($0) }))
 print (trimmed)
```

Comment: That's fine, the first option worked. My bad, I forgot to try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you can use to start the cleaning:

```
extension String {
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        let components = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).filter({!Swift.isEmpty($0)})
        return " ".join(components)
    }
}

var string = "  Lorem   \r  ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "
println(string.condenseWhitespace())
```

Add also this delegate method to your code:

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
       if range.location == 0 && string == " " {
           return false
       }
       return true
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 3** you can use:

```
//let myTextField.text = " Hello World"

myTextField.text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
// Result: "Helloworld"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let string = textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it while typing in TextFeild

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string == " " {
            textField.text = textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            return false
        }
    return true
}
```